# Does WebRTC allow to create audio, video and text chat?

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

I want to create audio, video and text messagtes chat. Is it possible using WebRTC? Or it only allow audio and video chats?

One side of my app will be implemented using browser. An other one - using C++ native API.

Does anyone have examples in native C++ API and/or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if WebRTC allows for text chatting. I was able to successfully create an Android Application that performed all of this, but only with the combination of Google's [Libjingle](https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) and [WebRTC](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/) libraries. Within the Libjingle library there are several example programs/pieces of code that demonstrate the library's functionality. The call example in Libjingle sounds very similar to what you are wanting to do, and is what I built my Android application out of. The only thing is I have not yet ported it to an web browser, so I am not sure if Libjingle will work with that.

I have begun looking into it, and I have [found some people on the WebRTC discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/discuss-webrtc/26UNDNm-q0w) that have developed a very nice Multi-user video chat application for a web browser that is built using WebRTC. It is capable of video (along with voice) communications as well as text chatting. I do not know if this matters, but it all occurs within a single interface (meaning that it does not seem to allow for separated/singular form communications -- text only, voice only, video only). I am sure that it would not be too difficult to separate them all out if you wanted/needed. They have posted all of their code onto [GitHub](https://github.com/webRTC) and seem to be actively updating and improving it.

Answer (score 2):

The WebRTC specification is still very much in flux, but there's a [DataChannel API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#peer-to-peer-data-api) in the spec that is implemented in an early form in both Firefox and Chrome. DataChannels are intended to allow you to send arbitrary bytes between peers, and the spec provides for both reliable (TCP-like) and unreliable (UDP-like) channels.